# OpenRasta in OWIN

Tags: owin, openrasta

I want to use OpenRasta in a Windows Service to accept REST calls and know it can be self-hosted by HttpListenerHost.  OWIN seems to be the latest and greatest self-hosted web server.  Is there an advantage to using OWIN over HttpListenerHost?  In terms of performance, flexibility, etc?  Is it even possible to use OpenRasta with OWIN?

Comment: Hi, I recently just wrote this but trying to find out if it's already been done before I opensource it. Will keep you informed or watch out on twitter @tomharrisnet

Answer (score 0):

Blake, we recently released a Owin middleware package on NuGet you can try out.

Some more details here
http://tech.just-eat.com/2014/10/07/opensourced-openrasta-middleware/

In addition to that I'm working on a vNext version as the IAppBuilder has now changed to IApplicationBuilder so need some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Thomas' answer, since 2.6 the Owin support started by Just-Eat has been moved to the main repository, and we have packages specifically targetting Katana and Mvc Core. A preview 3 will be released soon, but CI packages are of course available. More details are available at https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-core